# Multi-phase MS Office Application Level Add-Ins

Tags: excel, ms-office, vsto, excel-addins

I am tasked with upgrading a current add-in, and creating a new add-in for Office Excel.  The requirements dictate that these solutions be implemented as application level add-ins as opposed to document-level.   Each solution is isolated in a separate group within the same proprietary tab on the Office Ribbon.

Is is possible to have multiple application-level add-in solutions or must these be contained within one Visual Studio solution.  If they must be contained within a single solution what would be the best practice for tabling (and hiding from the end-user) the solution that is still a work in progress? \

**---APPEND---**

To clarify, I will define each programmatic entity to be accomplished as a task.  Each task is contained within a single group on the Ribbon.  All tasks/groups are on the same custom ribbon "tab".  How do I release these projects individually to end-users?  I should be able to release Task-A to to end-users without worry about the status of Task-B even though they are on the same ribbon tab?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in having all the application addin under single solution, I preferred to have it in a single solution in my projects.

With regards to hiding from the end user, if you are going for Click once deployment then just publish the addins which are ready for release. Even if you go for MSI you should be able to do the same by deploying only the addins which are ready to release.

You could also hide the ribbon tabs if they are not completed yet. Hope this answers your question.

***Reply to your Appended Question:***

In our project we just hide the buttons from the ribbon by setting Visible = False so that the  QA or enduser could not be able to see this hidden button. Eventhough there is unfinished/untested code they are never invoked.

Comment: Kiru, I do not understand how you can have separate projects that reference the same ribbon.   You cannot add a reference to an Excel Add-In within Visual Studio.

Comment: I had individual project for each ribbon tabs in Excel, Word and PowerPoint because there are different users where they have few tabs deployed for them and for some remaining few tabs. I am talking about application level addins.

Comment: Do you have multiple Ribbon objects contained within each project?

Comment: No only one instance of Ribbon. In my previous response I meant I have Excel Addin with three new ribbon tabs and I have individual project for each ribbon tab. So there are three addins deployed to the user.

Comment: I need multiple projects to have UIs on the same Tab.  I have a single Tab , each of which will have toggle buttons associated with custom task panes.

Comment: I dont think you can do this with Custom tab, but it should be possible with Office tab. If you use the IdMso = "TabAddIns" for all your ribbons everything would appear in a single ribbon tab.